# Call Web Service from AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I've looked through a number of posts/tutorials on calling a WS via AJAX, but am still not able to do this. Not that the environment matters but... I wrote my Java Class in Eclipse, I'm running it on GlassFish, and I'm able to hit the Endpoint via soapUI.

JAVA Class:

```
package com.tester.gf;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class GlassFishTestApp {

    public List<String> getBrands() {
        List<String> brands = new ArrayList<>();
        brands.add("Chevrolet");
        brands.add("Dodge");
        brands.add("Ford");
        return brands;
    }
}
```

Endpoint:

```
localhost:8080/GlassFishTestApp/GlassFishTestAppService?wsdl
```

When I load the following Web Page, I only see "Error: " displayed in the .

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SOAP WS Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax(
                    type: 'get',
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/GlassFishTestApp/GlassFishTestAppService',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#results').text(data);
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        $('#results').text('Error: ' + request.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
<html>
```

soapUI Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gf="http://gf.tester.com/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <gf:getBrands/>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

soapUI Respose:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getBrandsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://gf.tester.com/">
             <return>Chevrolet</return>
             <return>Dodge</return>
             <return>Ford</return>
        </ns2:getBrandsResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Thanks for any input on this!

Comment: Output the `error` argument in the `error` callback and see what it says.

Comment: Also, are you running you app from `localhost:8000`? If so, `/GlassFishTestApp/GlassFishTestAppService` is more clear that you are making a request to the current page's origin, and not a cross-origin request.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried the following, and still only see "Error: " in the output.

    $('#results').text('Error: ' + error);

Comment: Open your debugging console and try again. Do you see any errors?

Comment: I changed the url to: '/GlassFishTestApp/GlassFishTestAppService'.

I wasn't sure which "debugging console" you were referring to so I checked FireBug (no errors), and the Console in Eclipse -- and saw the following error: 

    SEVERE: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog.

That doesn't look good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
var soapMessage =
    '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gf="http://gf.tester.com/">' +
        '<soapenv:Header/>' +
            '<soapenv:Body>' +
                '<gf:getBrands/>' +
            '</soapenv:Body>' +
    '</soapenv:Envelope>';

$.ajax({
    url: "/GlassFishTestApp/GlassFishTestAppService",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    headers: {
        SOAPAction: "/GlassFishTestApp/GlassFishTestAppService/getBrands"
    },
    data: soapMessage,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#results').text(data);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        $('#results').text('Error: ' + error);
    }
});
```